# Is it possible to get the version of a shared object?

Tags: android, c++, linux, adb

I'm trying to track down a bug in my software line.  I have two release build version 2.0.962 and 2.0.966.  The only difference between these versions is a lib.so file.  In order to figure out where to start looking in the source tree for lib.so, I need to know its version number in each of the release builds.

Is there a command line tool for printing the version of a shared object?

Comment: I am not familiar with Android, but in Linux there is a command called `readelf` which can display information about dynamic libraries. For example, `readelf -a library.so`

Comment: You can integrate some binary artifact checksum generation into your build process. Then you will be able to look up the build version by the library file checksum

Comment: I'm not sure why our build tool (TeamCity) doesn't simply list the versions of artifact dependencies being pulled into the build...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never did native android programming but as Android uses Linux kernel, the executable format used will most likely be "ELF". As far as ELF is concerned, there is no version information of Shared object stored in the file. So unless the file name itself is saying something like `"libXXX.VERSION.so"`, there is no other way to find out the version number of the shared object. This technique is generally used in Linux.

My suggestions for solving your issue are:

1. Use Date modified if possible to differentiate the shared objects
2. Use dlopen() or similar to open the shared object and try to see the functions being exported.

Source: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html
Note: E_VERSION in the executable is the version of ELF format, not of executable.

Comment: I used option 1 prior to posting the question.  It made me sad that I had to resort to that so I asked the question hoping that there was a better way :)

Comment: The version of an SO is often in the ELF format, as part of SONAME: `readelf -a lib.so | grep SONAME`. When you link against a library at build time, that SONAME is what gets put into your executable (as an NEEDED section), and is how the linker finds the correct version of the SO to link at runtime. That said, there is no enforced naming/versioning and different libraries use different conventions, so it depends on what tools and options you used when creating your so as to whether the version is included, as well as what granularity (just major, or major & minor, etc)

Comment: Credits for `readelf` mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31463787/9962007) in... 2015 should arguably go to @escualo...